# How to select a number of random files from a given path using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to select a number of random files from a given directory. Below is my current implementation; however, there are too many files inside the folder iterating them all and then pick few random ones seems overkill.

Is there a better solution? Because what I am thinking is knowing all the files inside the folder is the precondition for random selection?

```
    const dirs = fs.readdirSync(IMAGE_BANK_SRC)
          .map(file => {
              return path.join(IMAGE_BANK_SRC, file);
          });

    const srcs_dup = [];

    dirs.forEach(path => {
        fs.readdirSync(path).forEach(file => {
            srcs_dup.push(file);
        });
    });

    // Pick few random ones from `srcs_dup`
```

**Requirements**:

1. The selected random files should be unique
2. The code is still working if the folder contains less files than expected
3. As fast as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically in the below code, I created randomIndex() which grabs a random file index. After you get the list of files. I do a while loop to grab a random file from the directory list and add it to the array.

```
  //Grabs a random index between 0 and length
  function randomIndex(length) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (length));
  }

  //Read the directory and get the files
  const dirs = fs.readdirSync(IMAGE_BANK_SRC)
    .map(file => {
      return path.join(IMAGE_BANK_SRC, file);
    });

  const srcs_dup = [];
  const hashCheck = {}; //used to check if the file was already added to srcs_dup
  var numberOfFiles = dirs.length / 10; //OR whatever # you want

  //While we haven't got the number of files we want. Loop.
  while (srcs_dup.length < numberOfFiles) {
    var fileIndex = randomIndex(dirs.length-1);

    //Check if the file was already added to the array
    if (hashCheck[fileIndex] == true) {
      continue; //Already have that file. Skip it
    }

    //Add the file to the array and object
    srcs_dup.push(dirs[fileIndex]);
    hashCheck[fileIndex] = true;
  }

  console.log(srcs_dup); //The list of your files
```

If this doesn't work. Let me know.

Answer (score 4):

Well, `readDir` & `readDirSync` return an array. You could avoid mapping through the entire array of paths by using the length property. We can make a dynamic sample set using a percentage of the length, then store the samples in a new array.

```
const dirs = fs.readdirSync(IMAGE_BANK_FILEPATH);
const length = dirs.length;
const sampleSet = 25/100 * length;
const getRandomIndex = length => Math.floor( Math.random() * length );

let samples = [];
let usedIndices = [];
let randomIndex = undefined;

for (let i = 0; i < sampleSet; i++){
  do {
    randomIndex = getRandomIndex( length );
  }
  while ( usedIndices.includes( randomIndex ) );

  usedIndices.push( randomIndex );
  samples.push( dirs[randomIndex] );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you no need to map to concat your directory path, this will loop through entire file 1 time.
Second, just loop number of files you need

```
let result = []
let requiredCount = 3;

let files = fs.readdirSync(IMAGE_BANK_SRC)

while(requiredCount-- && files.length) {
    let length = files.length;
    let selectedIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * length)
    let selected = files.splice(selectedIndex, 1);
    result.push(path.join(IMAGE_BANK_SRC, selected))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution better to have a `hashCheck` like @treeless did.

Comment: @LiXinyang if you understand Array.splice, it took out the item based on index. So why you still need to use hashCheck to check duplicate file? if you need to reuse variable files for other purpose after this, you can use Object.assign([], files) to make a duplicate of it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simplistic implementation.  You should also consider using the `path.resolve()` method.

```
const dirs = fs.readdirSync(IMAGE_BANK_SRC)
  .map((e) => { return path.join(IMAGE_BANK_SRC, e); });

// New random list of dirs
const randomList = dirs.slice(0)
  .map((e) => { return Math.random() < .5 ? e : null; })
  .filter((e) => { return e != null; });
```